# Appropriate js kendo template for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I use only kendo template in my website and use this js:
**kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/kendo.all.min.js**

but this file very very large size (**2.102 KB**). I want Appropriate kendo js file for this sulotion but I dont know:

my codes is:

```
<script>
    function FillSpecificationAttr(attrId) {
        var template = kendo.template($("#template").html());
        var ID = attrId;
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "../AjaxFunctionPages.asmx/ProductSpecAttrList",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {
                        ID: ID
                    }
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "../../AjaxFunctionsAdminPages.asmx/TierPriceDelete",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {
                        ID: ID
                    }
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    if (operation != "read") {
                        // web service method parameters need to be send as JSON. The Create, Update and Destroy methods have a "products" parameter.
                        return JSON.stringify({ ID: data.Id })
                    }
                    else if (operation == "destroy") {
                    }
                    else {
                        // web services need default values for every parameter
                        data = $.extend({ sort: null, filter: null }, data);
                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "d.Data"
            },
            requestStart: function () {
                kendo.ui.progress($("#tblConfigProduct"), true);
            },
            requestEnd: function () {
                kendo.ui.progress($("#tblConfigProduct"), false);
            },
            change: function () {
                $("#tblConfigProduct").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
            }
        });
        dataSource.read();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What happened ? Need help?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown hi. this js not work for template and 'kendo.data.DataSource'. when fetch datas and fill datasource errord.

Comment: Well, in your question you asked only about templates. I guess you have to add kendo.data.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the template is defined in `kendo.core.min.js` file which in version `2017.2.504` is only 54KB of size. You will still need jQuery library as a required dependency added in your document.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oVIhI)